# Change datetime format on a Google Graph timeline

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, graph, timeline

I have a Google Graph that shows Temperatures values / Epoch Datetime
I would like to toggle with a button the dates in X axis in 24h format like this : 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm' instead of current AM / PM format.

For some reasons, I can't get it working, dates stay in AM PM.
Can you tell me what is wrong ?

https://jsfiddle.net/lcoulon/ds7vgLvd/

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages': ['corechart']
});

google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);


function drawChart() {

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('datetime', 'Date');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Temperatures');

  data.addRows([
    [new Date(1485320400000), 22.5],
    [new Date(1485342000000), 23.8],
    [new Date(1485360000000), 24.2],
    [new Date(1485363600000), 21.0],
    [new Date(1485410400000), 25.5],
    [new Date(1485439200000), 23.0],
  ]);


  var options = {
    title: 'X Axis datetime epoch (ms) / Y Axis Temperature (°C)',
    width: 900,
    height: 500,
    hAxis: {

      gridlines: {
        count: 15
      }
    },
    vAxis: {
      gridlines: {
        color: 'none'
      },
      minValue: 0
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

  chart.draw(data, options);

  var button = document.getElementById('change');



  button.onclick = function() {

    // If the format option matches, change it to the new option,
    // if not, reset it to the original format.
    options.hAxis.format === 'M/d/yy' ?
      options.hAxis.format = 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm' :
      options.hAxis.format = 'M/d/yy';

    chart.draw(data, options);
  };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>

<button id="change">Click to change the format</button>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that according to [*the docs*](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datesandtimes), the date and time format is set separately (go to the very bottom of the page):

```
hAxis: {
      viewWindow: {
        min: new Date(2014, 11, 31, 18),
        max: new Date(2015, 0, 3, 1)
      },
      gridlines: {
        count: -1,
        units: {
          days: {format: ['MMM dd']},       // <-----
          hours: {format: ['HH:mm', 'ha']}, // <-----
        }
      },
      minorGridlines: {
        units: {
          hours: {format: ['HH:mm', 'ha']},       // <-----
          minutes: {format: ['HH:mm a Z', ':mm']} // <-----
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you RobG, applying this way has also modified the Vertical Axis from -1 to 1.  How could i set this axis to automatically suit the min and max datas range on Y axis ?   https://jsfiddle.net/lcoulon/ds7vgLvd/1/

Comment: I tried this with timelines (was not the question) and it did not work. However `hAxis: {format: 'HH:mm'}` worked for **changing google charts timeline to 24 hour display** - https://stackoverflow.com/a/61802783/936284