# Angular is it possible to translate content of tooltip in Google Gantt Chart

Tags: angular, google-visualization, gantt-chart

My html looks like that:

```
<google-chart #chart
   [title]="title"
   [type]="type"
   [data]="data"
   [columns]="columnNames"
   [options]="options"
   [width]="width"
   [height]="height">
</google-chart>
```

Its a Gannt Chart.

Tooltip looks like that:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIa5Q.png

How can I get dynamically "Duration" "Percent done" etc as a variable in my angular component.ts so I can modify them?

Comment: It seems like the angular component is only a wrapper for google-charts. I guess you need to extend the wrapper to get that functionality

Comment: you should be able to calculate the duration from the data you provide the chart, here is an example --> [Google timeline chart duration in hour](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38667796/5090771)